# Selecting child element on HTML and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have following two lines of codes which executes on multiple loop.

```
<label class="price">
    <em>Dynamic Value</em>
    <label class="price-actual" hidden>Actual Dynamic Value/label>
</label>
```

And following jquery function.

```
$('body').on('click', '.price',
    function (e) {
        var actualClicked = $(e.target);
        var clicked = actualClicked.children(".price-actual");
        alert(clicked.text());
    }
);
```

My requirement is when ever i click on price label, it will alert the value of actual dynamic value from its child class.

I did above code and it is not working fine. Please get me ride of it.

Comment: You cannot nest `<label>` elements. Case closed. `:)`

Comment: Also, use `this` instead of `e.target`

Comment: The `e.target` might change, instead use `$(this);`

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your HTML code with :

```
<div class="price">
    <em>Dynamic Value</em>
    <label class="price-actual" hidden>Actual Dynamic Value</label>
</div>
```

And Jquery with :

```
$('body').on('click', '.price',
    function (e) {
        var actualClicked = $(this);
        var clicked = actualClicked.children(".price-actual");
        alert(clicked.text());
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` for get element from where event is triggered.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.price',
    function (e) {
        alert($(this).children(".price-actual").text());
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="price">
    <em>Dynamic Value</em>
    <label class="price-actual" hidden>Actual Dynamic Value</label>
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
<label class="price">
<em>Dynamic Value</em>
<label class="price-actual" hidden>Actual Dynamic Value</label>
   </label>
<br>
 <label class="price">
<em>Dynamic Value</em>
<label class="price-actual" hidden>Actual Dynamic Value</label>
          </label>
                <br>
      <label class="price">
<em>Dynamic Value</em>
<label class="price-actual" hidden>Actual Dynamic Value</label>
```

and in js

```
$(document).on('click', '.price',
function (e) {
console.log('a');
    var element= $(this);
    var vale = element.closest('.price').find('.price-actual').text();
    alert(vale);
}
     );
```